# ionic user data returned by Ionic.User.current();

Tags: ionic-framework

Is there a reference manual somewhere that says what information is returned by a call to:

```js
user = Ionic.User.current();
```

In particular is there a unique ionic user ID returned?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Ionic v1.0 doc:](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/user-usage)

```
// this will give you a fresh user or the previously saved 'current user'
var user = Ionic.User.current();
```

Comment: Yes, but what I need to know is what data 'user' contains by default. For example I think there is user.is_authenticated but presumably there are others?

Comment: @BillNoble did you find out if there were? I need to get the email that the user signed up with but don't know how. Thanks

Comment: No never found the documentation for this and have decided to use Firebase instead.